# git hook script name - named appropriately

Tags: git, hook

The git hooks documentation says:

```
To enable a hook script, put a file in the hooks subdirectory of your Git directory that is named appropriately and is executable
```

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

What does it mean by `named appropriately`?

Comment: named after whatever hook you want the script to handle? https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html

Comment: It just means a name that you think is good for that script.. Remembere that the script must be executable, this is very important..

Comment: One would expect that you can simply create multiple hooks per type (for example pre-commit), and name them pre-commit-something-1 and pre-commit-something-2. But it seems you would have to implement your own pre-commit that runs multiple other hooks if you want to. No built-in solution similar to apache sites, modules or whatever ubuntu configs you might be used to. And it actually solves the problem with order of execution and the exit logic, because this way you have to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some example scripts in `.git/hooks` that show how to use hooks. Note that the name of the hook defines when it is called ; thus the hook names are pre-defined by git. You cannot pick your own names — git would simply ignore them.

Requirements for a working hook:

1. Correct name, see [all hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)
2. Executable
3. Placed in `.git/hooks/`

Further reading

- http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks
- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks